# Setting up rEFIt-based tripple boot system on a Mac with a pre-existing Boot Camp installation

Tags: bootcamp, efi

What I have right now is an iMac running Mountain Lion with a Boot Camp partition running Windows 7. I have a vanilla Boot Camp setup with no quirky bells and whistles on the side.

What I want is to install rEFIt so I can triple boot Mountain Lion, Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I've done this several time before and am aware of the process I need to go through, including how to handle the presence of 5 partitions on a system that can only handle 4.

What I don't want to have to do is wipe out my Boot Camp partition in order to do this. It's possible, since I only have games which can be reinstalled, but I have a lot of them and that would be a huge pain, so I'd like to avoid that route if possible.

**Question**: Is it possible to set up a rEFIt-based triple boot system while preserving a pre-existing Boot Camp partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just decided to go ahead with it and see what happens and rEFIt successfully picks up the Windows 7 partition as desired.

Following the [Lifehacker guide to triple booting](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple+boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required), there's a section that says

> If you've already installed Windows using Boot Camp, though, that's
>   fine—just ignore the Windows parts of this step